# MySQL query to find ids that do not exist in table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of ids pre-generated that I need to check if exist in a table. My table has two columns, `id`, `name`, where `id` is an auto increment integer and `name` is a `varchar(255)`.

I basically want to get a count of how many ids do not exist in table `foo` from my pre-generated list. So say my list has the numbers `5` and `10` in it, what's the best way to write something to the extent of:

`select count(*) from foo where id does not exist in ( 5, 10 )`

The idea here is that if 5 and 10 do not exist, I need the response `2`, and not the number of rows in `foo` that do not have the `id` 5 or 10.

Comment: how about `select count(*) from foo where id does not be am in ( 5, 10 )`

Comment: @Drew, sarcasm is not helpful.

Comment: @BillKarwin it is a little dash of humor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL; DR sample data and queries [at rextester](http://rextester.com/WSRJ85910)

> The idea here is that if 5 and 10 do not exist, I need the response 2, and not the number of rows in foo that do not have the id 5 or 10.

You should have provided a little more information to avoid confusion.

Example

```
id | name
 1 | tom
 2 | joe
 3 | mae
 4 | goku
 5 | vegeta
```

If your list contains `(1, 2, 3)` then your answer should be 0 (since all three are in the table )

If your list contains `(1, 2, 6)` then your answer should be 1. ( since 1 and 2 are in the table but 6 is in't )

If your list contains `(1, 6, 7)` then your answer should be 2.

If your list contains `(6, 7, 8)` then your answer should be 3.

> assuming this was your question

If you know the length of your list

```
select 2 - count(*) as my_count from foo where id in (5, 10)
```

The following query tells you how many are present in foo.

```
select count(*) from foo where id in (5,10)
```

So if you want to find those that do not exist, subtract this result from the length of your list.

```
select n - count(*) as my_count from foo where id in (5, 10,....)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use on fly table using union and the a left join

```
select count(*) 
from my_table as m
left join ( 
    select 5 as id from dual 
    union 
    select 10 from dual ) t on t.id = m.id
where t.id is null
```

otherwise you can populate a tempo table with the value you need and use left join 
where the value is null

Comment: I had to edit my post, what I need is not the rows that do not match those, but the count of how many in the list do not match. So if 5 and 10 do not exist, the query would return `2`

Comment: I have changed my answer